# Why ebean.properties doesn't work in play 2.4?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I used ebean in my project, and I want to show sql with ebean, however,

```
ebean.ddl.generate=true

ebean.ddl.run=true

ebean.debug.sql=true

ebean.debug.lazyload=false

ebean.loggingToJavaLogger=true

ebean.logging=all

ebean.logging.logfilesharing=all

ebean.logging.directory=/logs

ebean.logging.iud=sql

ebean.logging.query=sql

ebean.logging.sqlquery=sql

ebean.logging.txnCommit=none
```

the config doesn't work at all.

And I also configured `db.***.logSql = true` in application.conf and `<logger name="logger.org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger" level="INFO"/>` in logback.xml (jdbcdslog.jar has been downloaded)

Comment: Please include what you expect and what's not working.

Comment: @Roman I was using ebean as my project ORM, I need to show sql so that i can debug some problem, however, ebean.properties doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to play2.4 has deprecated the log config in `application.conf`, we need to config in the `logback.xml` with `<logger name="org.avaje.ebean.SQL" level="TRACE"/>`, thats enough.

Answer (score 1):

None of those ebean.logging properties are valid.

Refer to http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/logging ... for information on all the logging configuration but you probably should including transaction logging and summary logging as well.

```
  <!-- SQL and bind values -->
  <logger name="org.avaje.ebean.SQL" level="TRACE"/>

  <!-- Transaction Commit and Rollback events -->
  <logger name="org.avaje.ebean.TXN" level="TRACE"/>

  <!-- Summary level details -->
  <logger name="org.avaje.ebean.SUM" level="TRACE"/>
```